# No Play Store on Samsung Galaxy Note 5 Chinese version

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-note-5

I have Samsung Galaxy Note 5 (Chinese version). Due to the Chinese version, I'm unable to download the Google Play Store.

How can I update my device with Google Play Store in India?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Google Installer.

After downloading it, install the app and open it, then download all listed Google Apps (Google Play Services, Google Play, and more).

It worked on my **HTC Desire 826 Chinese**.

Comment: Looks like the link to Google Installer is dead now (I removed it for now). Is there an alternative source for it?